# ¿Como guardar letras con acentos en un arreglo?

Tags: c++, array, acentos

Estoy realizando un programa que reciba una frase o palabra, ya use la libreria
`<locale.h>` para poder mostrar estos caracteres con acento, el problema es que si el usuario ingresa una ñ por ejemplo el programa no reconoce este caracter y lo que sigue despues del caracter.

```
fflush(stdin);
p("\nIngrese palabra o frase a encriptar: "); gets(frase_encrip);
```

Posteriormente cuando quiero imprimir "frase_encrip" uso:
   `p("\nFrase encriptada: "); puts(frase_encrip);`

[image: Por ejemplo ingreso la palabra Niño]

Pero a la hora de imprimir solo pone lo que hay antes de la ñ...

[image: Pero lo que me imprime en la primer linea es Ni y más adelante ya encriptada la frase solo pone pi]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba incluyendo la cabecera `windows.h` y modificando el código de página de entrada usado por la consola:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");
SetConsoleCP(1252); 
SetConsoleOutputCP(1252);
```

Al parecer este problema solamente sucede en SO Windows porque en Linux no es necesario más que utilizar `setlocale`

Comment: Sabrías decirme, por qué no `setlocale(LC_ALL, "")`? Yo acostumbro a usarlo así y no tengo ningún problema. Por cierto, otra página de código para la consola que puedes usar es la de UTF-8 (65001)

Comment: Con `""` se utiliza el idioma que está configurado en tu sistema operativo local. Si utilizas `"spanish"`
 se es más específico con el idioma a utilizar. [setlocale](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/setlocale-wsetlocale?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Gracias por el dato